# Using PyCharm, Can't Seem to Import Pyperclip module

Tags: python, pyperclip

When I type `pip install pyperclip`, I get:

```
Collecting pyperclip
  Using cached pyperclip-1.5.27.zip
Installing collected packages: pyperclip
  Running setup.py install for pyperclip ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/70/2rxbr83d37xgqtk215y88p_m0000gn/T/pip-build-0mgGiQ/pyperclip/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/70/2rxbr83d37xgqtk215y88p_m0000gn/T/pip-7v2hjv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/pyperclip
    copying pyperclip/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyperclip
    copying pyperclip/clipboards.py -> build/lib/pyperclip
    copying pyperclip/exceptions.py -> build/lib/pyperclip
    copying pyperclip/windows.py -> build/lib/pyperclip
    running install_lib
    creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyperclip
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyperclip': Permission denied



Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/70/2rxbr83d37xgqtk215y88p_m0000gn/T/pip-build-0mgGiQ/pyperclip/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/70/2rxbr83d37xgqtk215y88p_m0000gn/T/pip-7v2hjv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/70/2rxbr83d37xgqtk215y88p_m0000gn/T/pip-build-0mgGiQ/pyperclip/
```

Comment: You are installing it system level, which requires 'sudo'. You should look in to using virtual environments instead: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to make the necessary directories. Either do this:

```
sudo pip install paperclip
```

or the better and preferred solution, install `virtualenv`. Plenty of SO examples, here's link:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/